# Refresh WPF label

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to dynamically refresh the label that shows the current amount of space remaining but unfortunately the number doesn't refresh. Do you have any idea how to solve my problem?

**C#**

```
private void ReqDescText_Changed(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
     Counter ReqDescText_Counter = new Counter(ReqDescText, ReqDescLabelLength);
}
```

**Class**

```
public class Counter
{
     public TextBox InputTextbox { get; set; }
     public Label CounterLabel { get; set; }
     public Counter(TextBox InputTextbox, Label CounterLabel)
     {
          int NB;
          TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
          var tempText = textBox.Text;
          NB = (InputTextbox.MaxLength - tempText.Length);
          CounterNumber counterNumber = new CounterNumber { Number = NB.ToString() };
          CounterLabel.Content = counterNumber;
          if (NB == 0)
          {
               CounterLabel.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
          }
      }

      class CounterNumber
      {
          public string Number { get; set; }
          public override string ToString()
          {
              return "[" + Number + "]";
          }
      } 
}
```

**WPF**

```
<Label x:Name ="ReqDescLabel" Content="Description" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,5,0,5" Grid.Column="0"/>
<Label Name="ReqDescLabelLength" FontSize="10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,6"/>
<TextBox x:Name ="ReqDescText" Padding="3" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,5" Grid.Column="2" TextWrapping="Wrap"  SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" MaxLength="250" TextChanged="ReqDescText_Changed" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
```

**How it's looks like**

[image]

Comment: Hi! Please show some of your XAML.

Comment: Added. WPF code should be find. I think this is something with a C# class. Earlier it worked well when I used the code inside "ReqDescText_Changed". The problem appeared after moving the code to the Counter class.

Comment: The most apparent problem is that you create new objects all the time (a new counter in the change event, a new textbox in its constructor). Think a bit more about the architecture and what the responsibility of each class are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. My mistake. 
I did't take the current length of the text.

```
 public class Counter
    {
        public TextBox InputTextbox { get; set; }
        public Label CounterLabel { get; set; }
        public Counter(TextBox InputTextbox, Label CounterLabel)
        {
            int NB;
            var tempText = InputTextbox.Text;
            NB = (InputTextbox.MaxLength - tempText.Length);
            CounterNumber counterNumber = new CounterNumber { Number = NB.ToString() };
            CounterLabel.Content = counterNumber;
            if (NB == 0)
            {
                CounterLabel.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
        }
        class CounterNumber
        {
            public string Number { get; set; }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return "[" + Number + "]";
            }
        } 
    }
```